# Maximum Total Supply

Tags: stellar-core, token, stellar-laboratory

What is the maximum Total Supply can be created for token in Stellar? I tried to make 100,000,000,000,000 but can't.

Answer (score 3):

Maximum asset amount an account can hold is determined by the particular trustline settings and may be up to [**922,337,203,685**](https://www.stellar.org/developers/guides/concepts/assets.html#amount-precision-and-representation). Total asset supply is unlimited.

Comment: Just adding to this I was able to get slightly over this amount on Testnet 922,337,203,685.4770000 (note: I stopped trying after 3 decimal places, because it was tedious on the Stellar Lab site. May be able to write a script to get the actual max supply.

Answer (score 0):

So I just did a little [DuckDuckGoing](https://duckduckgo.com/) and it looks like this is the max int64 9223372036854775807 as described in the [Stellar Laboratory](https://laboratory.stellar.org) change_trust limit, so if they put the decimal after the 5 and before the 4, then the true maximum amount of a particular asset an account can hold would be:

922337203685.4775807

Edit: I found it in the docs too https://developers.stellar.org/docs/issuing-assets/anatomy-of-an-asset/#amount-precision